# Change header background color on scroll

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Need help changing my header background color when scrolling. This is what i have thus far.

header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const header = document.querySelector('.header');
    document.addEventListener('scroll', (ev) => {
      if (header !== null) {
        if (window.scrollY === 0) {
          header.classList.remove('change-header-background');
          return;
        }
        header.classList.add('change-header-background');
      }
    });
  }

}
```

header.component.scss

```
.header {
    border-top: 0.5rem solid #000;
    position: fixed;

    .change-header-background {
        background-color: white;
    }    
}
```

I have tried multiple suggestions i have found online, but none seemed to work.

Comment: Logic seems fine on Javascript side, maybe put some debug points and check if the class is actually updating, if yes then are the class definitions loading properly in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youe have a mistake in your css:

```
.header {
    border-top: 0.5rem solid #000;
    position: fixed;

    .change-header-background {
        background-color: white;
    }    
}
```

you need to add `&` before your `.change-header-background` like this:

```
&.change-header-background
```

to apply style to your header class.

Without ampersand `&` the class `.change-header-background` will refer to any descendat element of element with class `.header`.
But with `&.change-header-background` will refer direcly to the element with class `.header`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion not a solution, but I suggest trying to animate the background change using `@keyframes` in your css instead of doing it in your ts component.

you could write something like this

```
@keyframes headerColorChange {
  0% {background-color: black;}
  50.0% {background-color: white;}
  100% {background-color: black;}
}
```